# Difference between a method in data or a method in methods in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am wondering what s the difference between a method declared in data, or a method declared in methods?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#vue-app",
  data: {
    name: function() {
      console.log("Alex");
    }
  },
  methods: {
    name: function() {
      console.log("Alex");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** If all you have inside is a `console.log("Alex")`, they will work the same. But if you have a `this` inside them, they will differ greatly.

---

Firstly, Vue `data` objects are expected to be plain JavaScript objects, without methods. From [**the API docs**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”. **The object must be plain**: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with their own stateful behavior.

So, even if it worked, I'd declare them in `methods` to follow the [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

## A crucial difference:

But, more importantly, there's a key factor: **methods are bound to the Vue instance**. Which means the **`this` inside methods** always point to the current Vue instance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nameData: function() {
      console.log("nameData", this.otherMethod()) // doesn't work
    },
  },
  methods: {
    nameMethod: function() {
      console.log("nameMethod", this.otherMethod()); // works
    },
    otherMethod() {
      return "I am other method";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="nameData">invoke nameData</button><br>
  <button @click="nameMethod">invoke nameMethod</button>
</div>
```

Yet another example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    id: 3,
    ids: [1,2,3,4],
    equalsIdData: function(i) {
      return this.id === i;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    equalsIdMethod: function(i) {
      return this.id === i;
    },
    yetAnotherMethod: function() {
      console.log('equalsIdMethod:', this.ids.filter(this.equalsIdMethod)); // filters correctly
      console.log('equalsIdData:',   this.ids.filter(this.equalsIdData)); // filters incorrectly
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="yetAnotherMethod">invoke yetAnotherMethod</button>
</div>
```

Comment: "Whereas a method declared in a data property is only accessible when you reference that property directly.".  Well, i can access that property(name) from data directily from otherMethod too, with the same this.name() .

Comment: Again, i understand the POLA factor, but for me is still working, if i use  <button @click="nameData()">invoke nameData</button><br> : https://jsfiddle.net/Lgoq8qs3/3/

Comment: Besides you **having** to add `()`, it works, but it is is accidental. Check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/Lgoq8qs3/12/